# Trouble reading last line of CSV

Tags: powershell

I am getting CSV files (with no header) from another system. The last line ends the file, (there is not a newline after the last line of data).  When I try Import-CSV, it will not read the last line of the file.

I do not have the ability to have the input file changed to include the newline.

I have noticed that the Get-Content doesn't have a problem reading the entire file, but then it isn't a CSV and I'm unable to reference the fields in the file.

Currently I'm doing:

```
$w = Import-CSV -path c:\temp\input.txt -header 'head1', 'head2', 'head3'
```

This will not read the last line of the file

This reads the entire file:

```
$w = Get-Content -path c:\temp\input.txt
```

But the data doesn't have the ability to reference the fields like:  $w.head1

Is there a way to get Import-CSV to read the file including the last line?
OR Is there a way to read in the data using Get-Content, adding a header to it and then converting it back to a CSV?

I've tried use ConvertTo-CSV but have not had success:

```
$w = Get-Content -path c:\temp\input.txt 
$csvdata = $w | ConvertTo-CSV    # No header option for this function
```

I'd rather not create an intermediate file unless absolutely necessary.

Comment: Your probably confused because `$csvdata` is not really the appropriate name for your result, meaning that you shouldn't use *Convert**To**-CSV* but  *Convert**From**-CSV*. Thus: `$csvdata = Get-Content -path c:\temp\input.txt` and than: `$data = $csvdata | ConvertFrom-CSV -header 'head1', 'head2', 'head3'`

Comment: I'm curios what version you have, because I have 7.1 and 5.1 and on both Import-Csv seems perfectly capable of reading a file without a CR or LF at the end of the last line. What does $PSversionTable give you?

Comment: I have the same question of @Martin Brown

Comment: PowerShell Version 5.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're very close! What you're after is not `ConvertTo-Csv`, you already have the file contents in CSV-format after all. So change that to `ConvertFrom-Csv` instead, which incidentally *does* support the `-Headers` parameter. So something like this:

```
$w = Get-Content -path c:\temp\input.txt 
$csvdata = $w | ConvertFrom-Csv -Header 'head1', 'head2', 'head3'
```

Comment: This is perfect - Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you know the number of columns in the file and all it is missing is a header line.  Since in your code you do not specify a `-Delimiter` parameter I'm assuming the delimiter character used in the file is a comma.

Best thing to do IMHO is to create a *new* output file and always keep the original.

```
$fileIn  = 'c:\temp\input.txt'
$fileOut = 'c:\temp\input.csv'
# write the header line to a new file
Set-Content -Path $fileOut -Value 'head1,head2,head3'
# read the original file and append it to the one you have just created
Get-Content -Path $fileIn -Raw | Add-Content -Path $fileOut
```

If your file is *really* large, below a faster alternative:

```
$fileIn  = 'c:\temp\input.txt' 
$fileOut = 'c:\temp\input.csv'
# write the header line to a new file
Set-Content -Path $fileOut -Value 'head1,head2,head3'
# read the original file and append it to the one you have just created
[System.IO.File]::AppendAllText($fileOut, ([System.IO.File]::ReadAllText($fileIn)))
```

If you really do want to take the risk and overwrite the original file, you can do this:

```
$file = 'c:\temp\input.txt'
$content = Get-Content -Path $fileIn -Raw
# write the header line to a the file destroying what was in there
Set-Content -Path $file -Value 'head1,head2,head3'
# append the original content to it
$content | Add-Content -Path $file
```